# .getText grabbing text before user is able to input

Tags: java, swing

My program has three functions (excluding exit): read to a file, search within a file and write to a file. I have this fully functional as a console app, and am working on a GUI (Swing) for it. I have the main window with all of the components created and functional (button click -> does function via console). What I'm after now is a complete cut-out of t=my need of the console.

I am working on this change on the Read function only (at the moment) so I can get it working properly. The issue I'm having is that the user is not able to specify the desired file (type path) inside the JTextField & click the buttonn corresponding to the desired function before the value (null) gets grabbed and assigned to a file variable.

Here is the class containing everything, except the classes containing the specific functions, I linked to it via main:

```
public class SimpleDBGUI{
static File targetFile;     //Declare File var to be used in methods below for holding user's desired file

public void mainWindow(){


    //Create main window for Program
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Simple Data Base");     //Init frame
    mainWindow.setSize(500, 180);       //Set frame size
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);        //Make frame visible

    //Create panel for the main window of the GUI
    JPanel simpleGUI = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    mainWindow.getContentPane().add(simpleGUI);         //Adds JPanel container to the ContentPane of the JFrame

    //Create button linking to read function
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read");       //Init button, and give text
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 2;
    gbCons.weightx = .1;
    readButton.setActionCommand("Read");
    readButton.addActionListener( new ButtonClickListener());
    simpleGUI.add(readButton, gbCons);      //Adds the "Read" button to the JPanel

    //Create button linking to the search function
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");       //Init button with text
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 1;
    gbCons.gridy = 2;
    gbCons.weightx = .1;
    searchButton.setActionCommand("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener( new ButtonClickListener());
    simpleGUI.add(searchButton, gbCons);        //Adds the "Search" button to the JPanel

    //Create button linking to the write function
    JButton writeButton = new JButton("Write");     //Init button with text
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 2;
    gbCons.gridy = 2;
    gbCons.weightx = .1;
    writeButton.setActionCommand("Write");
    writeButton.addActionListener( new ButtonClickListener());
    simpleGUI.add(writeButton, gbCons);         //Adds the "Write" button to the JPanel


    //Create label prompting user to specify desired function
    JLabel promptText = new JLabel("Click 'Read' to read a file, 'Search' to search within a file, 'Write' to write to a file:");       //Give user a prompt to select desired function
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 0;
    gbCons.gridwidth = 3;
    simpleGUI.add(promptText, gbCons);      //Add prompt to the JPanel

    //Create button to exit program
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 3;
    gbCons.gridwidth = 3;
    exitButton.setActionCommand("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener( new ButtonClickListener());
    simpleGUI.add(exitButton, gbCons);      //Add "Exit" button to the JPanel

    //Create TextField for user to input a desired file
    JTextField sdbTarget = new JTextField();
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 1;
    gbCons.gridwidth = 3;
    simpleGUI.add(sdbTarget, gbCons);               //Adds TextField to GUI
    targetFile = new File(sdbTarget.getText());     //Writes input string to a File var, works but out of time resulting in null value
}

public class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{         //Sets the EventListener for every function

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        //targetFile = File(sdbTarget.getText());           //Was a proposed solution, but kept giving type resolving errors
        try{                                                                            //Leftovers from the console version of the app,
            Scanner inputChoice = new Scanner(System.in);                               //these were left so my Search and Write functions would still work in the console
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Joshua/Desktop/jOutFiles/SimpleDB.txt");     //
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);                             //

            String function = event.getActionCommand();                                 

//Reads the ActionCommand into a string for use in performing desired function
                if( function.equals("Read")){                                               //Read function
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();                                 //For the GUI version, supposed to open "targetFile" upon readButtonClick
                    desktop.open(targetFile);                                               //
//                  SimpleDBReader sdbrObject = new SimpleDBReader();                       //Bit left from console version, still functional
//                  sdbrObject.sdbReader(inputChoice, file);                                //
                }else if( function.equals("Search")){                                       //Search Function
                    SimpleDBSearch sdbsObject = new SimpleDBSearch();
                    sdbsObject.sdbSearch(inputChoice, writer, file);
                }else if( function.equals("Write")){                                        //Write function
                    SimpleDBWriter sdbwObject = new SimpleDBWriter();
                    sdbwObject.sdbWriter(inputChoice, file);
                }else if( function.equals("Exit")){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing, like most GUIs is event driven, that is, something happens and you respond to it.  You code is rather linear in approach, you create your UI components, but then, even before the UI has been presented to the user, you do `targetFile = new File(sdbTarget.getText());`

But `sdbTarget` has not had any values applied to it yet.

But better solution would be to use your `ActionListener`, `ButtonClickListener` to inspect the value

```
String target = sdbTarget.getText();
if (target != null && !target.trim().isEmpty()) {
    File targetFile = new File(target)
    String function = event.getActionCommand();                                 //Reads the ActionCommand into a string for use in performing desired function
    if (function.equals("Read")) {                                              //Read function
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();                                 //For the GUI version, supposed to open "targetFile" upon readButtonClick
        desktop.open(targetFile);                                               
        //...
```

This way, you'll always be evaluating the `targetFile` every time `actionPerformed` is called

Comment: Thanks, I got it going now. Do you know why it cut my code short when I tried to upload it?